# RTMFP player for Android?

Tags: android, flash, video-streaming, rtmfp

I am writing an Android application and I need to be able to watch RTMFP p2p streams with an arbitrary groupsection on the device through my app. On desktop I use a simple web page that looks like the following:

```
<html>
<head><title>asdf</title>
</head>
<body>
<object data="http://p2p.peer-stream.com/api/strobe-1.6-sec-v3.swf" name="player_playerdiv" id="player_playerdiv" bgcolor="#000000" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="854" height="480">   <param value="true" name="allowFullScreen" />   <param value="always" name="allowScriptAccess" />   <param value="direct" name="wmode" />   <param value="src=http://peer-stream.com/api/get_manifest.f4m?groupspec=G:somegroupsec&amp;autoPlay=true" name="flashvars" /> </object>
</body>
</html>
```

On Android, I have installed Flash Player 11.1, but although the player loads, it never loads any streams and eventually shows TypeError (error 1009). I've also tried Flash 10.3 with the same result. Are there any solutions or alternatives?